# lambda function with if statement to return mode

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda, mode

I want to get the most repeated value of a column but I also want to add a condition that picks the 2nd highest value if the most repeated item is 'None'. for example:

item_name = [apple, orange, orange, None, None, None]
In this case I want the code to return "orange" as the most used item.

I came with this code but I get invalid syntax error - any idea how can I get it fixed?

```
df['most_used_item']= df.groupby('user_id')['item_name'].transform(lambda x: x.mode().iat[1] if x =='None' else x: x.mode().iat[0])
```

Comment: `else x: x.mode().iat[0]` is a syntax error -- ternary expressions are written `val_if_true if condition else val_if_false` -- you need `else x.mode().iat[0]`

Comment: Why not just filter `None` out?

Comment: Remove `x:` after the `else`.

Comment: Pro tip: use a named function instead of a lambda. This will give you the freedom to add whatever complexity you wish without the restriction of a single expression that a lambda imposes.

Comment: I do still need to keep 'None' as a category so cannot treat it as nan

Answer (score 0):

`mode` ignores null value by default:

> **dropna** : bool, default True
>
> Don't consider counts of NaN/NaT.

You can use:

```
df['most_used_item'] = (df.groupby('user_id')['item_name']
                          .transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0]))
print(df)

# Output
  user_id item_name most_used_item
0       A     apple         orange
1       A    orange         orange
2       A    orange         orange
3       A      None         orange
4       A      None         orange
5       A      None         orange
```

If `None` is a string, replace `'None'` by `NaN`:

```
df['most_used_item'] = (df.replace('None', np.nan)
                          .groupby('user_id')['item_name']
                          .transform(lambda x: x.mode()[0]))

# OR  df.replace({'item_name': {'None': np.nan}})...
```